# How to set up USB mouse to wake up closed laptop

Tags: linux, debian, usb, acpi

I have Dell XPS 13 9360, screen Dell UltraSharp U2715H - LED monitor 27" and a cheap USB mouse.

The mouse is plugged in the screen USB hub which is plugged in my main USB hub which is plugged in my laptop.

I use the external screen and the laptop lid is closed all the time. How do I set up ACPI to be able to wake up the laptop via mouse click after `acpitool -s`?

Here is tree

```
~ » lsusb -t

/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=ax88179_178a, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 19, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 23, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 23, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 23, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 4, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 21, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 24, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
                |__ Port 3: Dev 25, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
                |__ Port 1: Dev 26, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 22, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 22, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Device 22 is the mouse.

Here is `lsusb`:

```
~ » lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:670c Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e300 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 0451:3410 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB3410 Microcontroller
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 024: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 04d9:a096 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 18f8:0f97  
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 041e:322c Creative Technology, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 020: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The mouse is 5th row from the bottom (Device 28)

ACPI configuration:

```
~ » cat /proc/acpi/wakeup 

Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
RP09      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:3c:00.0
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:3a:00.0
RP06      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:3b:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *disabled
XHC   S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
SS06      S0    *disabled  no-bus:usb2-port6
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
PBTN      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

I use Debian buster/sid.

Comment: Does a USB keyboard work to wake it? Not sure about on laptops, but often BIOS settings may allow one to configure what sources are allowed to wake up the computer such as PCI or USB.

Comment: It seems like it's the matter of OS not bios. Everything related to USB is on in BIOS.

Comment: Have you find out how to achieve this?

Comment: no I didnt...sorry